# How to relaunch a coroutine on each Fragment.onResume call?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-lifecycle, kotlin-flow

I have some coroutine that should be relaunched on each `onResume()` call of `Fragment`.

I have tried the following approach:

```kotlin
val renderer = ...
val outerFlow = ...
val lifecycleCoroutineScope = myFragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope

lifecycleCoroutineScope.launchWhenResumed {
   outerFlow.onEach(renderer::render).launchIn(this)
}
```

But it only works until the `Fragment`'s view destroyed first time. I mean the second and the following `onResume()` calls became ignored.

So please help me to find out: **how to properly launch my coroutine on each `onResume()` call?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue.

The problem was not in coroutines. It was in `LifecycleOwner`.
After `Lifecycle` gets `Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED` state it also destroys and doesn't work anymore.

I was bound to `Fragment` view's lifecycle. And after we leave the current Fragment, its view's lifecycle gets destroyed.

**So replacing `fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` to `fragment.lifecycleScope` helped me.**

Answer (score 1):

I believe it doesn't work because of calling `launchIn(this)`. Please try to call another terminal operator, like `collect`:

```
lifecycleCoroutineScope.launchWhenResumed {
   outerFlow.collect(renderer::render)
}
```

---

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleCoroutineScope#launchWhenResumed(kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) they say that:

> This API is not recommended to use as it can lead to wasted resources in some cases. Please, use the `Lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle` API instead. This API will be removed in a future release.

With the `Lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle` it will look something like the following:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
        outerFlow.collect(renderer::render)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately after few tests it doesn't help. The behavior is the same

Comment: Using `repeatOnLifecycle` doesn't work as well?

Comment: Yep, but I found the answer. I'll post it soon.